# Re-enabling Ondemand cpu frequency scaling

Tags: 14.04, cpufreq

I ran

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
```

to disable on-demand cpu frequency scaling.

Can it be re-enabled again running

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand enable
```

os: ubuntu 14.04 lts.

Comment: Maybe you should try it and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust CPU frequency with indicator-cpufreq available in the software center. See below. I've never tried your method.

[image: indicator-cpufreq]

Comment: Works pretty well for me on 14.04.

Comment: @axel22 I use it on 16.04 as well. I've found it useful for down-clocking my system during periods of heavy load accompanied by unseasonably warm weather. Normally I leave it set on OnDemand, but sometimes conditions warrant setting it at a specific clock rate.