# Intel Core M underclocking at 10% battery

Tags: asus, intel, 17.04

I'm wondering if someone could point out how I could go about stopping my Asus UX305FA running Ubuntu 17.04 on an Intel Core M from underclocking itself when the battery is low.

It goes from the normal 950MHz - 1000MHz down to 400MHz - 500MHz range when the battery gets to 10% power remaining.

I'm hoping I can just edit a file without having to install a heap of tools to do it. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 16.04 does the same (haven't observed the actual clock values, but it severely slows down) with my i5-6200U too, so I'd be interested in an answer as well.

Comment: Ubuntu does not do this so it sounds like an annoying "feature" of your BIOS.  See if it has an option to turn it off.

Comment: Nothing like that in mine, it has very minimal options.

Comment: I have a UX305 too. My issue is, when the ambient temperature increases, or if the ultrabook is not sufficiently cool, it underclocks from 1.4GHz to 0.7GHz and man, does it go slowww. I had to get a cooling pad

Answer (score 0):

First of all install: The pm-utils package comes with scripts for managing low-power modes.

To install it:

```
sudo aptitude install pm-utils
```

From a Terminal you can do:

```
sudo pm-powersave false
```

to run in high-performance mode.

And to run in powersave mode:

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

Comment: This changes the scaling governor but the frequency still seems to be low, both the powersaver and performance governor scale between 500MHz and 2GHz so when the battery percent is at 10%, they both choose to lower the frequency to the minimum possible. I can't seem to manually set the frequency either, I assume I have the arguments set right `sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.5 GHz`

Comment: This is your solution->https://askubuntu.com/questions/598224/cpu-frequency-control